# Back accent or grave accent in listings

Tags: listings

I'm using listings to display a bash script like for instance

```
$ export MY_ENV=`pwd`
```

How can I make listing display the correct character for `. Right now it is displaying '

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, article, oneside, a4paper]{memoir}

% Files encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish, es-noquoting, es-tabla]{babel}
%es-noquoting era por el tikz

\usepackage[spanish]{translator}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%Listings
\usepackage[final]{listings} % to be shown independently draft of final
\lstdefinestyle{CommandLineStyle}{
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  numbers=none,
%  frame=tblr,
  columns=fullflexible,
%  backgroundcolor=\color{blue!10},
  linewidth=0.95\linewidth,
  xleftmargin=0.05\linewidth,
  breaklines=true,
  breakindent=1em,
%  inputencoding=utf8/latin1,
%  postbreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\color{red}\hookrightarrow\space}},
%  breakautoindent=true
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=CommandLineStyle]
$ export MY_ENV=`pwd`
\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `listings` package provides the `upquote` toggle option to determine how the left and right quote are printed. Setting it to `true` does what you want (works similarly to setting the literate as in egreg's answer). This requires loading the `textcomp` package before the option is set.

```
\documentclass[article]{memoir}

\usepackage{textcomp} % <--- for other glyphs, so can use upquote option of listings

\usepackage[final]{listings} % to be shown independently draft of final
\lstdefinestyle{CommandLineStyle}{
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  numbers=none,
  upquote=true% ensure that backtick displays correctly
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=CommandLineStyle]
$ export MY_ENV=`pwd`
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image: Backticks are displayed correctly]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `literate` feature of `listings` and the `\textasciigrave` macro of `textcomp`. I have reduced the example to the essential.

```
\documentclass[article]{memoir}

\usepackage{textcomp} % <--- for other glyphs

\usepackage[final]{listings} % to be shown independently draft of final
\lstdefinestyle{CommandLineStyle}{
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  numbers=none,
%  frame=tblr,
  columns=fullflexible,
%  backgroundcolor=\color{blue!10},
  linewidth=0.95\linewidth,
  xleftmargin=0.05\linewidth,
  breaklines=true,
  breakindent=1em,
%  inputencoding=utf8/latin1,
%  postbreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\color{red}\hookrightarrow\space}},
%  breakautoindent=true,
  literate={`}{\textasciigrave}{1}, <--- real back quote
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=CommandLineStyle]
$ export MY_ENV=`pwd`
\end{lstlisting}
```

[image]

But if you're using Bash, why not

```
export MY_ENV=$(pwd)
```

which is also simpler to print? `;-)`

Comment: the bash was just an example, it is a more complicated line ;) Both answers are equally valid.